# Select rows where I want values in column to have multiple values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, select

I have a dataframe with multiple columns.

```
df= pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Jake', 'Jake'],
    'Product' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B']
    })


    Name Product
0  Peter       A
1  Peter       B
2  Peter       C
3   Jake       A
4   Jake       B
```

The columns have `name` and `product`.

How can I select those `name`s with multiple products, for example product `A`, `B`, and `C`. In other words, I want Peter which has `A`, `B`, and `C`, but not Jake because he only has `A` and `B`.

Edit: I don't want that the `name`s have JUST A, B, and C, but I just want to see if they have `A`, `B`, and `C`. So if Peter has `D` (which is not included in the sample) it is fine as well.

I tried:

```
df[(df.Product == 'A') & (df.Product == 'B') & (df.Product == 'C')]
```

But this yields no results.

```
df[(df.Product == 'A') | (df.Product == 'B') | (df.Product == 'C')]
```

And this one just concatenates the rows.

Comment: You can archive this with A subselect:

`WHERE SELECT COUNT(*) XX > 1`

Comment: Doesn't A and B are multiple products?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way `isin` with `filter` - but slow if large data:

```
df=df.groupby('Name').filter(lambda x : pd.Series(['A','B','C']).isin(x['Product']).all())
df
    Name Product
0  Peter       A
1  Peter       B
2  Peter       C
```

Test case From Jez

```
df= pd.DataFrame({
    'Name': ['Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Jake', 'Jake','Jake'],
    'Product' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B','A']
    })
df.groupby('Name').filter(lambda x : pd.Series(['A','B','C']).isin(x['Product']).all())
    Name Product
0  Peter       A
1  Peter       B
2  Peter       C
```

Base on what he provided `'Product' : ['A', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B','A']`

```
df.groupby('Name').filter(lambda x : pd.Series(['A','B','C']).isin(x['Product']).all())
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Name, Product]
Index: []
```

Comment: @jezrael why? cause of speed ?

Comment: @jezrael see the test case

Comment: @jezrael that is why i mentioned to you at the beginning speed problem

Comment: @IvanLibedinsky hi, man thank your support , it is safe to use . :-) just speed kind of slow . :-)

Comment: Cheers guys! I was trying something like `df_aux = df.groupby('name')['id'].apply(lambda x: list(x)).reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'name'})
df = df.merge(df_aux,how='left',left_on='name',right_on='name')` but wasn't getting anywhere.

Comment: @WeNYoBen I'll accept your answer. Because it was what I was looking for. I didn't want JUST `A`, `B`, and `C`, but I just want if they have `A`, `B`, and `C`. So if Peter has `D` it is fine as well.

Comment: @Mataunited18 - hmmm, so need `df[df.groupby('name')['product'].transform(lambda x: set(x) >= set(lst))]` ?

Comment: @jezrael Yes! The speed of your solution is much faster.

Comment: @Mataunited18 - yop, reason is `filter` is unfortunately slow in pandas...

Comment: @Mataunited18 - OK, so happy coding. And if small data use any solution ;)

Answer (score 4):

If want test each group has exactly 3 unique values of list then compare `set`s anf filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
lst = list(['A','B','C'])

df = df[df.groupby('name')['product'].transform(lambda x: set(x) == set(lst))]
print (df)
    name product
0  Peter       A
1  Peter       B
2  Peter       C
```

If need test values of list with any another values:

```
df= pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Peter', 'Jake'],
    'product' : ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'B']
    })
lst = list(['A','B','C'])

df = df[df.groupby('name')['product'].transform(lambda x: set(x) >= set(lst))]
print (df)
    name product
0  Peter       A
1  Peter       B
2  Peter       C
3  Peter       D
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC and a given name should contain all products, you could use `nunique` to count the amount of unique products. Then check that grouping by `name` there are as many unique counts in that group as in the whole column:

```
prods = df['product'].nunique()
df[df.groupby('name')['product'].transform('nunique').eq(prods)]


    name    product
0  Peter       A
1  Peter       B
2  Peter       C
```

Comment: The way I've understood it is to keep those in which all products are specified. Yet I might be wrong, that part is not really clearly specified enough @ivan

Comment: So what is *multiple products*? Does it seem like a clear value to you? Will it be defined by OP in each case? Is it the distinct products? If so its only a matter of changing `df['product'].nunique()` by the length of the deifned `set` of products @juan

Comment: Well if that is what op wants yes the solution would be to predefined a list of products. But again, to me it is unclear @juan

Answer (score 0):

The question is unclear, I assume that OP is interested in **all** products `A,B,C`. Then one can do:

```
s = (df.groupby('Name')['Product']
       .transform(lambda x: x.value_counts()
                          [['A','B','C']].gt(0).all()
                 )
    )

df[s]
```

Output:

```
    Name Product
0  Peter       A
1  Peter       B
2  Peter       C
```